# Fingerprint enrollment and verification via browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fingerprint

I have a digialPersona fingerprint reader and I'm working on a web application which is to have fingerprint enrollment and verification functionalities.

Is it possible to do this via the browser? Is yes, how?

If no, what are the best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-The *print reader (Hardware)* will have some api reference library for interfacing. You may write `Custom ActiveX control` in Winforms / C# or C++ (depending the SDK library ref) & load it via `Javascript`.

-One more option is to use [Full trust WPF browser application](http://nahidulkibria.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/how-to-run-wfpxbap-in-full-trust-mode.html) (XBAP)

**NB:** Beware of client side privileges settings in these scenarios

Comment: I'll look at the activex control aspect but I think I'll settle for the WPF solution. Thanks.